# Pulling upon a grafted branch?

Tags: git

I did `git fetch --depth=1 origin master` and now I want to `git pull` again, but it tries downloading everything rather than recent commits. Can I only download commits later than my grafted commit, rather than creating another grafted commit?

Comment: If you're fetching instead only merge. Don't pull (which is a fetch _and_ a merge).

Comment: True, but to merge I have to fetch the target commits somehow, right?

Comment: Isn’t that what you said you’ve done? You did “git fetch” and now you want to “merge” not “pull”.

Comment: No, I made a grafted branch by `fetch --depth 1` and I want to load more recent commits from the remote.

Comment: What do you mean by "made a grafted branch"? Take a look at [the fetch docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) maybe theres an option you might want?

Comment: [`--shallow-exclude`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---shallow-excludeltrevisiongt) does look like an answer except it doesn't work with GitHub

Comment: What is the reason for it not working on github?

Comment: Using the option for a GitHub repo causes connection error.